# Read from txt file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I'm having problems reading in from a txt file in matlab. The txt file is an online review, so the delimeter I want to use is just a single whitespace. I've tried using dlmread, textscan and textread but can't seem to get it to work. I want each word in the txt file to be in a seperate cell in an array. How do I go about this?

Thanks

EDIT, this is the txt file

> My husband and I satayed for two nights at the Hilton Chicago,and
>   enjoyed every minute of it! The bedrooms are immaculate,and the
>   linnens are very soft. We also appreciated the free wifi,as we could
>   stay in touch with friends while staying in Chicago. The bathroom was
>   quite spacious,and I loved the smell of the shampoo they provided-not
>   like most hotel shampoos. Their service was amazing,and we absolutely
>   loved the beautiful indoor pool. I would recommend staying here to
>   anyone.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the file you are trying to read? Also, what did not work with the different methods you tested?

Comment: The problems have been to do with the format
'Mismatch between file and format string.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textread('your_filename', '%s')` should work.

Comment: currentReview= textread('fold1/d_hilton_1.txt', '%s');
This works thank you, however how do i access a cell?
currentReview(1);

Comment: 'currentReview{1}' is what you need

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails (other answers already seem good, but you specifically said the functions they proposed do not work), try something like this:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
for i = 1:1000
    A{i} = fscanf(fid,'%s',1);
end
fclose(fid)
```

Just make sure your loop is long enough to read every word.

Comment: To avoid having to predict the number of words, maybe you could replace the for loop with a while loop by using the end-of-file indicator (`A={};while(~feof(fid))A{end+1}=fscanf(fid,'%s',1);end`).

Comment: Regardless, wouldn't it be inefficient in either case to grow `A` each iteration of the loop?